# nested routing in angularJs help required

Tags: angularjs

I want to have nested routing in angular-

In User.html, i will have three sections add, edit ,delete.
On click of add it should route to user/add and redirected to add.html and same for others.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$anchorScroll** but that will not change your url mean you will stay on the same page and it will just scroll you to the section. As i can understand you want to have different actions on the same page, there are many ways to do so like angular like ng-show and ng-hide. You you the user edit view on demand and so with the add user. You can use same form for add new and edit. there is a tutorial on [Angular page](https://angularjs.org/) if you scroll down there is a section **Wire up a Backend** and that's something you want in your application i guess :-)